# How to make default blob an image in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, image, blob, default

I know how to upload images to my database but how can I make a longblob's/blob's default an image from my computer instead of just being null?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to set DEFAULT property to BLOB column (except NULL, of course) is to specify it as an expression.

If you want to set DEFAULT value as some image, then you may:

1. Load this image into BLOB column. For example

```sql
CREATE temptable (blob_column BLOB) 
SELECT LOAD_FILE('image_filename') AS blob_column;
```

2. Convert loaded binary value to some textual representation which can be typed in the table definition. For example, use HEX() function

```sql
SELECT HEX(blob_column) 
FROM temptable;
```

Long string literal will be obtained in the output.

3. Use obtained literal (copy-paste, avoid excess linebreaks/spaces/truncation/etc.) in the expression of the DEFAULT value of the BLOB column. Apply the expression which reverses the convertion applied at the step 2. Like

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablename ( ...
                         blob_column_name  BLOB DEFAULT (UNHEX('long HEX literal')),
                         ... );
```

Pay attention to the parenthesis which wraps the expression (UNHEX() function in shown example) - they're compulsory! Single `DEFAULT UNHEX('long HEX literal')` will produce syntax error.